# Развернуть рекурсивный алгоритм в обычный цикл. Путь Эйлера

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, visual-studio, графы

Есть некий направленный мультиграф. Задаётся он при помощи **списка рёбер**.
Минимально каждое ребро должно хранить информацию "Откуда" и "Куда".

Нужно найти **все комбинации** при которых захватываются **все рёбра** графа
(Как я понял это алгоритм нахождения **пути Эйлера**)

Я написал алгоритм в виде рекурсии ( логика такова что я разворачиваю свой граф в дерево и простым DFS прохожусь по ветвям, если дошёл до конца - добавляю в ответ +1 ).
Написано на C#, однако, думаю, смогу понять ответ и на других яп.

> Задача: Развернуть рекурсию в обычный цикл.

Вот мой код:

```cs
public class Movement
    {
        public int From = 0;
        public int To = 0;
        public Movement(int from, int to)
        {
            this.From = from;
            this.To = to;
        }
        
        public int FindMovements(List<Movement> container)
        {
            int result = 0;
            bool existFlag = false; // Флаг, говорящий, остались ли вообще перемещения
            int temp = container.IndexOf(this);

            container.Remove(this);
            for (int i = 0; i < container.Count; i++)
            {
               existFlag = true;
               if (container[i].From == this.To)
                    result += container[i].FindMovements(container);
            }
            container.Insert(temp, this);

            return existFlag ? result : 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: В чём заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: `я разворачиваю свой граф в дерево` что это значит?

Comment: @norix , Я указал в заголовке и в сноске - Развернуть рекурсию в обычный цикл while.

Comment: я просто не улавливаю что ваш код делает. Это бессмыслица какая то.

Comment: `все комбинации при которых захватываются все рёбра графа` найти комбинации или число комбинаций?

Comment: @tym32167 , Формально, DFS линеен, как я понял, и для мультиграф надо развернуть до дерева всех вариантов перехода. У меня есть картинка визуализации процесса - могу скинуть
[ https://imgur.com/a/UXqOMxh ]

Comment: тогда к вашкму алгоритму будет одна претензия - скорость. Вы по сути проверяете все комбинации всех ребер. Постройте полный граф из 1000 вершин и попробуйте дождаться, когда алгоритм завершит работу.

Comment: @tym32167 , Не совсем, чем глубже рекурсия опускается, тем меньше элементов становится. За это отвечает `Remove` и `Insert` после отработки ветки. Если попадётся широкий граф без большой глубины - алгоритм отрабатывает за доли секунд. Однако в глубоких графах соглашусь, время растёт в шустро. Поэтому и пытаюсь оптимизировать максимально.

Comment: потому я и написал про полный граф. 1000 вершин - это небольшая глубина, но в полном графе это означает 2 миллиона ребер.

Comment: @Young Sideways Не стоит надеяться, что алгоритм с экспоненциальной сложностью (что неизбежно) станет быстрее работать при превращении рекурсии в цикл.

Comment: @MBo станет, быть может на порядок даже быстрее. Но для экспоненты это конечно не делает погоды.